# Installing MacVim issue with 'src/' directory and ./configure command

Tags: installation, macvim

The MacVim Readme_mac says I need to cd to a directory called 'src/', but it doesn't exist by default. Should I just create it or does it absence raise a flag?

also when I do `$ ./configure --help` it returns `'No such file or directory'`

Comment: Where did you get the Readme_mac file. Did you download and extract a source tarball?

Comment: I downloaded from GitHub as the std zip DL https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim

Comment: How did you extract the zip? I have no experience with OSX, but I remember that the old DOS and windows unzipped (pkunzup.exe) tended to put all files in a single directory. A proper extract should have created a structure like this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/01uiv.png